# create a pandas data frame based on available elements of a column of a different data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically, I have a data frame in which `b` could contain just `1`,just `2` or a combination of `1` and `2`. In case it has only one of the elements (eg `1`) then the missing element (eg `2`) should get a value of, say, `0`.

For example if `df = pd.DataFrame({'value':np.random.randn(3), 'b':[1,1,1]})`

the resulting data frame should look like:

```
  value    b
-0.160580  1
0.100649   1
1.402768   1
0          2
```

However, if `df = pd.DataFrame({'value':np.random.randn(3), 'b':[2,2,2]})`

```
  value    b
0          1 
-0.390148  2
0.843670   2
-0.199137  2
```

If `df = pd.DataFrame({'value':np.random.randn(3), 'b':[1,2,2]})`

```
  value    b
-0.912213  1
-1.827496  2
0.995711   2
```

I though of initiating a data frame:

```
df_init = pd.DataFrame({'value':[0,0],'b':[1,2]})
```

and then updating it with whatever values `df` has and placing them according to whether `b` is `1` or `2`, but don't know how to do this...

Answer (score 0):

You could just `append` if 2 isn't in the column:

```
In [11]: df.append(pd.Series({'value': 0, 'b': 2}), ignore_index=True)
Out[11]: 
   b     value
0  1  1.601810
1  1  1.483431
2  1 -0.781733
3  2  0.000000

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

To check, use set on the column first (more efficient if you're reusing and have a smaller number of possible values):

```
In [12]: b_unique = df.b.unique()

In [13]: b_unique
Out[13]: array([1])
```

That is,

```
In [14]: if 2 in s: # equivalently use if 2 in df['b'].unique()
             df.append(pd.Series({'value': 0, 'b': 2}), ignore_index=True)

In [15]: df
Out[15]: 
   b     value
0  1  1.601810
1  1  1.483431
2  1 -0.781733
3  2  0.000000

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```

*You can do the same check for 1.*

Comment: @Boud That's a good point, you could use that (it'll be smaller), however set uses hash table so more consistent lookups.